# Machine Learning: Balanced training set but highly unbalanced prediction set? How to adjust?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, class-imbalance

I am trying to train a model to detect gender in a dataset of CEO speeches. Here are the datasets that I have:

1. Final Dataset: 20K CEO voices analyzed (around 95% male)
2. Testing dataset (?): 1K CEO voices analyzed from the final dataset, less unbalanced because I added more females on purpose (80% male)
3. Training dataset: 6K voices analyzed from audiobooks and TED talks (55% male).

For now, I have been trying different models by training and splitting dataset #3 (70%, 30%). I get good accuracy (95%) using this method. However, when I apply the trained model to dataset #2, I get an accuracy of 85%.

I am not sure what to do. Should I undersample women in the training dataset so that its distribution is more similar to the final dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over- or undersampling should be your second choice. Currently, the best method to deal with class-imbalances is to use the `weights` argument which sklearn- and keras-classifiers support (see for example the [DecisionTreeClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html)).

On a general sidenote, I would recommend focusing on the f1-score,  AUC, and the confusion matrix to evaluate the model's performance, as accuracy might be not as informative in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice.